# how does Matlab normalize generalized eigenvectors?

Tags: matlab

I know that the eigenvectors produced by eig(A) have 2-norm 1. But what about the vectors produced in the generalized eigenvalue problem eig(A,B)? A natural conjecture is that such a vector v should satisfy v'*B*v=1. When B is the identity matrix, then v'*B*v is exactly the square of the 2-norm. I ran the following test for various matrices A and B:

```
[p,d]=eig(A,B);
v=p(:,1);
v'*B*v
```

I always choose B to be diagonal. I noticed that v'*B*v is not always 1. However, it is indeed 1 when A is symmetric. Does anyone know the rule for the way that Matlab normalizes the generalized eigenvectors? I can't find it in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#btgapg5-1-V) (emphasis mine):

> The form and normalization of V depends on the combination of input arguments:
>
> - [...]
> - `[V,D] = eig(A,B)` and `[V,D] = eig(A,B,algorithm)` returns `V` as a matrix whose columns are the generalized right eigenvectors that satisfy `A*V = B*V*D`. **The 2-norm of each eigenvector is not necessarily 1**. In this case, `D` contains the generalized eigenvalues of the pair, (`A`,`B`), along the main diagonal.
>
>   When `eig` uses the `'chol'` algorithm with symmetric (Hermitian) `A` and symmetric (Hermitian) positive definite `B`, it **normalizes the eigenvectors in `V` so that the `B`-norm of each is 1**.

This means that, unless you are using the `'chol'` algorithm, `V` is not normalized.

Comment: It also says "When you omit the algorithm argument, the eig function selects an algorithm based on the properties of A and B. It uses the 'chol' algorithm for symmetric (Hermitian) A and symmetric (Hermitian) positive definite B. " This explains that when A and B are symmetric, then the vector is indeed B-normalized.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you are looking for a way to generalize a vector then **given a vector you can divide it by its norm to obtain a secondary vector whose norm is 1**.

If you are looking for the mathematical background, then [Eigendecomposition of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) contains a good introduction.